# Kubernets prisma server not reachable

Tags: kubernetes

I'm setting up a Kubernetes which is compose by `prismagraphql` and `Postgres` locally.

The Postgres container is setted up correctly and by using a `NodePort` I can access it from pgadmin locally.

Instead the prisma container is not reachable. I followed these steps ([Guide](https://v1.prisma.io/tutorials/deploy-prisma-to-kubernetes-ct13)) but I'm not able to find it at localhost:4466 also after the forwarding process.

[image: kubectl get all]

[image: error when I try to reach localhost:4466]

This is the `postgres.yaml`:

```
# postgres config
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: database
  POSTGRES_USER: username
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
---
# postgres deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  serviceName: "postgres"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:12
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-configuration
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgresdb
---
# postgres service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      name: postgres
```

This is the `prisma.yaml`:

```
# prisma config
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prisma-config
  labels:
    app: prisma
data:
  PRISMA_CONFIG: |
    port: 4466
    databases:
      default:
        connector: postgres
        host: database
        port: 5432
        user: username
        password: password
        migrations: true
---
# prisma deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prisma-deployment
  labels:
    app: prisma
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prisma
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prisma
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prisma-4466
          image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4466
          env:
            - name: PRISMA_CONFIG
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: prisma-config
                  key: PRISMA_CONFIG
---
# prisma service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prisma-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: prisma
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 4466
      targetPort: 4466
      nodePort: 30100
```

This is what I obtained with `kubectl describe svc prisma-service`:
[image: kubectl describe svc prisma-service]

Comment: The Pod doesn't have the label `stage: production`, so the Service doesn't connect to it.  You should be able to see this if you look at the endpoints listing in `kubectl describe service prisma`.

Comment: @DavidMaze I updated the answer by simplifying the labels. The problem is that I'm not sure if it is correct that the labels of the service is empty by using the command `kubectl describe svc prisma`.